# Why does 'node .' always throw an error when I type it in cmd?

Tags: javascript

I just started with my first discord bot and I am really stuck with this problem. Everytime I write 'node .' it gives an error stating this 'throw new TypeError('CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS');'can anybody tell me what I need to fix?

That's all the code I got:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const token = 'myToken';

bot.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('This bot is online!');
})

bot.login(token);
```

[picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHa90.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `intents` field when initializing the Client. Read more about intents [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Intents)

```
const bot = new Discord.Client({ intents: [Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
```